# Django problems with media and image in template

Tags: python, django

Have a problem, try to do simple gallery in django, but when i tried to check how it looks, picture doesn't show anything only title name and there is at terminal "Error 404 not found". Can't realise what actually is wrong... Please help. thx...

Not Found: /media/images/example.png
[16/Mar/2016 17:59:17] "GET /media/images/example.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2168

models.py

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Название альбома", max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField("Ссылка на альбом", max_length=100, unique=True)
    img = models.ImageField("Изображение альбома", upload_to='images', 
            help_text='Размер изображения 200px на 200px')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Название фотографии", max_length=100)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='Альбом')
    img = models.ImageField("Фото", upload_to='images', 
            help_text='Желательно не большой размер')
```

urls.py - app

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import Album, Photo

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
    model=Album,
    context_object_name='my_album',
    template_name='gallery/album.html'),
    name='gallery'
    ),
  url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
    model=Album,
    context_object_name='photos',
    template_name='gallery/photo.html'),
    name='photo'
    ),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                    document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py - project

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^gallery/', include('gallery.urls')),
]
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

template

```
{% extends "gallery/base.html" %}
{% load thumbnail %}
{% block title %}My Gallery{% endblock %}

{% block text %} 
    {% for album in my_album %}

        <a href='{{ album.slug }}'>
        <img src="{{ album.img.url}}" alt="{{ album.title }}">

          <!-- {% thumbnail album.img "200x200" crop="center" as im %}
            <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="{{ im.title }}" width="{{ im.width }}" 
        height="{{ im.height }}">
            {% endthumbnail %} -->

        </a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

ProjectStructure

```
ProjectFolder/
    app/
        migrations/
        static/
        templates/
        admin.py
        models.py
        ..
    project/
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ..
    media/
        images/
            example.png
    my_env/
    manage.py
```

if in setting.py i do MEDIA_URL = 'media/images' it will work, but only for album template if you will go to see album photos, there photo won't shows too with the same error... Actually i can't understand and realise how to do access to folder media and just bring any of content placed here what i need. Help me...

Comment: Can you share directory structure related to example.png? Remember /media starts from the directory where manage.py is present.

Comment: Is your DEBUG setting set to true in your settings.py ?

Comment: Sure, its on true, actually i tried do both true and false.

Comment: can you edit your image url to this? `  <img src="/images{{ album.img.url}}" alt="{{ album.title }}">`  faced a similar problem recently and fixed mine by appending the name of the directory before it, not sure if it's best practice though.

Comment: Not working at all =\ Just added new images befor media "GET /images/media/images/"

Comment: Fix this problem. Just created new project on Django 1.8.6 instead 1.9